# How to develop subscribe user module in php

Tags: php, subscribe

I want to develop a subscribe user module in PHP in which the user will get all the notifications about the activity of the subscribed user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create  **Subscriptions**, **UserSubscriptions** tables, you already have **Users** table (I assume).

insert all notification names into **Subscriptions** table you want to send, **UserSubscriptions** table will have **UserId** and the **SubscriptionId**.